# T-SQLHelp - Generating Ids

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a set of data where I need to generate SetIds. Basically, if I where to walkthrough the first dataset with an order on column ID, I want to increament a counter everytime I hit a RecordType of 5. See the second sample on desired output.

```
Id     RecordType  Amount
----------------------------
1          5         1.00
2          6         1.00
3          7         3.00
5          5         1.00
6          6          .50
7          6          .50
8          8         1.00
9          5          .05

Id     RecordType  Amount   SetId
-------------------------------------
1          5         1.00     1
2          6         1.00     1
3          7         3.00     1
5          5         1.00     2
6          6          .50     2
7          6          .50     2
8          8         1.00     2
9          5          .05     3
10         6          .05     3
```

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial sample data was missing ID 10

```
DECLARE @Table Table (Id Int, RecordType Int, Amount Decimal(9,2))
Insert Into @Table (Id,RecordType,Amount) Values
(1,5,1),
(2,6,1),
(3,7,3),
(5,5,1),
(6,6,.5),
(7,6,.5),
(8,8,1),
(9,5,.05),
(10,6,.05)

Select *
      ,SetId = Sum(IIF(RecordType=5,1,0)) over (Order by ID) 
 From  @Table
 Order By Id
```

Returns

```
Id  RecordType  Amount  Flag    SetId
1   5           1.00    1       1
2   6           1.00    0       1
3   7           3.00    0       1
5   5           1.00    1       2
6   6           0.50    0       2
7   6           0.50    0       2
8   8           1.00    0       2
9   5           0.05    1       3
10  6           0.05    0       3
```

Comment: @vin OK, that made me smile.   Thanks for that'

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @DataX TABLE (
      Id            INT IDENTITY
    , RecordType    INT
    , Amount        DECIMAL(5,2)
    , SetId         INT
    )

INSERT INTO @DataX (RecordType, Amount) VALUES
      (5,1)
    , (6,1)
    , (7,3)
    , (5,1)
    , (6,.5)
    , (6,.5)
    , (8,1)
    , (5,.5)

; WITH SetId
    AS (
        SELECT Id, SUM (CASE WHEN RecordType = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS SetId
            FROM @DataX
        )

UPDATE dx1
    SET dx1.SetId = (SELECT SetId.SetId)
        FROM @DataX dx1
            JOIN SetId
                ON dx1.Id = SetId.Id

SELECT * FROM @DataX
```